# Faster alternative than loop through list to specify non unique values and their position

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a data set from which I need to isolate and feedback non-unique values across multiple columns. (Think multi column primary key violation in database table). I am currently doing this by concatenating those columns on each row into a `List<string>`. Doing a count of the item in the list and if greater than 1 adding an error message to **another column on the same row** - that bit's important, I need to be able to provide feedback on the position of the duplicate/s, not just the fact that there is a duplicate.

The problem is speed, although this technically works, it doesn't work well as a practical solution because I will potentially be working with data sets of several hundred thousand rows

Code:

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
string ThisConcat = "";
for (int i = 0; i < dtLogData.Rows.Count-1; i++)
    {
       foreach (int ColNum in ColNumList)
       {
           ThisConcat += dtLogData.Rows[i].Field<string>(ColNum-1);
       }
       mylist.Add(ThisConcat);
       ThisConcat = "";
    }
```

Then:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtLogData.Rows.Count-1; i++)
{
    int count = mylist.Count(j => j == mylist[i]);
    if (count > 1)
    {
      dtLogData.Rows[i][ColCnt] = MyErrorString;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Move the hard work to the sql server and use `distinct`. This will be orders of magnitude faster (for large number of records) compared to pulling down all records and processing locally.

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20754/DataTable-with-SelectDistinct-in-C

Comment: @Gone Coding I am not pulling this data from the server, it is coming from excel/text files, it needs to go into the server and I'm trying to vet it and provide feedback in an automated way such that the insert will not run if there are issues (I push the excel file back to the user with an error column). That said I understand i could load the the dataset into the server and manipulate it there, but how to provide the positional feedback I want? I.e. this line is a duplicate please amend, for the affected lines

Comment: Quick question: have you *tried* it with your full sized data set? I don't know where this process sits in your business, but before you go optimizing, make sure you need to.

Comment: @hometoast Yup, tried with 80,000 rows, some of my real data sets will be twice that size at least, the rest of the error checking completes in a couple of seconds the duplicate check took a couple of minutes, too long for my case

Comment: @HelloWorld did you test my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you a slightly different solution. This assumes you are willing to add another column to the DataTable:

```
dtLogData.Columns.Add("hash");
```

Then you cast the table:

```
var t = dtLogData.AsEnumerable();
```

First you compute the concatenated string and get a hold of the rows. You can do this in two ways. If you want to limit the columns to certain indexes (like your original code):

```
var rows = t.Select(row =>
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        ColNumList.ForEach(i => builder.Append(row[i]));
        row["hash"] = builder.ToString();
        return row;
    }
);
```

Or if you just want to use all columns:

```
var rows = t.Select(row =>
    {
        row["hash"] = string.Join("", row.ItemArray.Select(i => i.ToString()));
        return row;
    }
);
```

You then grab all the rows with duplicates and mark them accordingly:

```
foreach (var dataRow in rows.GroupBy(r => r["hash"]).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).SelectMany(g => g))
{
    dataRow[ColCnt] = MyErrorString;                
}
```

Comment: `builder.Append(row[i-1])` as my `ColNumList ` is not zero based. Both this answer and @VV5198722 are proving to be much quicker than my original solution. Upvote for both I will test with a full real dataset and accept the answer that is quickest. Thanks

Comment: I've marked this one as accepted, the speed test wasn't much different between the two but this seems the simpler solution and the second part only loops duplicates on the hash column...probably....I need to do some lambda tutorials...

Comment: Thank you @HelloWorld. I am glad we could help. Out of curiosity, what's the difference in time from your original solution? :-)

Comment: I didn't test my original solution with the full dataset as it was so much slower than the two other solutions with a 1/4 dataset. However with 1/4 datset my original and innat3 took around 80 seconds. Yours and VV5198722 took around 6 seconds (And that's with other validation checks still going on as well)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>>` instead of `List<string>` and store row references to each `ThisConcat` tupel.

```
Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>> mylist = new Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>>();
string ThisConcat = "";
for (int i = 0; i < dtLogData.Rows.Count - 1; i++) {
    foreach (int ColNum in ColNumList) {
        ThisConcat += dtLogData.Rows[i].Field<string>(ColNum - 1);
    }
    if (! mylist.ContainsKey(ThisConcat)) 
        mylist[ThisConcat] = new List<DataRow>();
    mylist[ThisConcat].Add(dtLogData.Rows[i]);
    ThisConcat = "";
}
foreach (var p in mylist) {
    if (p.Value.Count > 1) {
        foreach (var r in p.Value) {
            r[ColCnt] = MyErrorString;
        }
    }
}
```

You call `mylist.Count` for each row. If you have n rows with almost different tuples, you get quadratic runtime complexity O(n^2). The code above should have linear complexity O(n).

Comment: Can you provide a code example to better round out your answer?

Answer (score -1):

You try can replacing the first bit of code with this one:

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
StringBuilder sb;

foreach (DataRow row in dtLogData.Rows)
{
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    ColNumList.ForEach(i => sb.Append(row[i - 1]));
    mylist.Add(sb.ToString());
}
```

And the second part with:

```
mylist.Select((a, b) => new { count = mylist.Where(c => c.Equals(a)).Count(), index = b })
    .Where(e => e.count > 1).ToList().ForEach(f => dtLogData.Rows[f.index][ColCnt] = MyErrorString);
```

Gotta love them downvotes with no explanation

Comment: not yet, trying to understand the second part, lambda is not my forte, I am new to C# and usually write linq etc in sql style syntax (I nicked the lambda bit in my code from another stack overflow question). ps that's not my downvote, thanks for trying to help